# OpenGL drawing Triangles only white

Tags: c++, opengl

I try learing OpenGL with those two tutorials:
https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle and 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEETnX-uPtBXT9T-hD0Bj31DSnwio-ywh

When I draw a simple triangle it is only white. But the code seems right.
This is the fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 1.0);
}
```

This is the `ShaderProgram`:

```
ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram(std::string fileName)
{
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    if (vertexShader == 0)
        std::cerr << "VertexShader creation failed! " << std::endl;
    const char* vertexShaderSource = (SourceLoader(fileName + ".vs")).c_str();
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    CheckErrorMessages(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, false, "VertexShader Compilation failed! ");

    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    if (fragmentShader == 0)
        std::cerr << "FragmentShader Creation failed! " << std::endl;
    const char* fragmentShaderSource = (SourceLoader(fileName + ".fs")).c_str();
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    CheckErrorMessages(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, false, "FragmentShader Compilation failed! ");

    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    CheckErrorMessages(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, true, "Program linking failed! ");
    glValidateProgram(program);
    CheckErrorMessages(program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, true, "Program validation failed! ");
}
```

I have three methods in the `ShaderProgram` class:
1. a method to load the shader code, which is definitly working.
2. a method to Check for Error Messages, which is also working.
3. and a `bind()` Funktion which is just using `glUseProgram(program)`

I also have a class for the window, which is created by SDL

```
Display::Display(std::string title, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
{
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    m_glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);

    GLenum status = glewInit();
    if (status != GLEW_OK)
        std::cerr << "GLEW failed to initialize!" << std::endl;

    isClosed = false;
}
```

the `Display` class has a method to update and clear:

```
void Display::Update()
{
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_window);

    SDL_Event e;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
    {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            isClosed = true;
    }
}

void Display::Clear(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)
{
    glClearColor(red, green, blue, alpha);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

I also have a class called `Mesh` to manage VAO and VBO etc.:

```
Mesh::Mesh(Vertex* vertices, unsigned int numVertices)
{
    drawCount = numVertices;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertices * sizeof(vertices[0]), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertices[0]), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

}
```

`Mesh` has one Funktion to draw the given vertices:

```
void Mesh::Draw()
{
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, drawCount);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

The `main` Funktion consists out of a while loop:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    Display display("Fenster", 1024, 840);

    ShaderProgram shader("./res/Shader");

    Vertex vertices[] = { Vertex(glm::vec3(1, 1, 0)), Vertex(glm::vec3(1, -1, 0)), Vertex(glm::vec3(-1, -1, 0)) };

    Mesh mesh(vertices, 3);

    while (!display.getIsClosed())
    {
        display.Clear(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        shader.Bind();
        mesh.Draw();
        display.Update();
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is I don´t get any Error, but the triangle keep staying white.
Thank you for helping!

Edit: Vertex Shader is here:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: There is way too much functions you didn't show us. You should construct a [mcve].

Comment: yes sorry i meant glUseProgram

Comment: I don't see how your triangle could be white if you output vec4(0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 1.0) in your shader. Change stuff in your fragment shader and vertex shader and see what effect it has, something may have gone wrong when creating your shader program. When this has happened to me I've had the wrong shader program or pipeline bound.

Comment: @p. peet Show us your vertex shader too.

Comment: Well the vertexShader is working, but i just tried to change the fragment shader. It seems like it has no influence at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your infoLog you'd find that your shaders aren't compiling. You're assigning the shader source pointer to a temporary string that gets destroyed at the end of the line, and you're sending gibberish to the shader compiler:

```
const char* fragmentShaderSource = (SourceLoader(fileName + ".fs")).c_str();// After this line the pointer isn't valid
glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
```

SourceLoader returns a temporary string, and you assign fragmentShaderSource pointer to the string. Then there is junk data there by the time you pass it to glShaderSource. You can do:

```
std::string vertShaderString = SourceLoader(fileName + ".vs");
const char* vertShaderSource = vertShaderString.c_str();
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertShaderSource, NULL);
```

You also need to fix the same problem for the fragment shader.
Also you drew a clockwise winding triangle, which is fine, but by default OpenGL considers counterclockwise winding as front-facing.

Another thing, the reason you didn't catch the error is because you CheckErrorMessages doesn't do anything, you should be writing the infoLog to the string or something.

Comment: Yes that was it. Thank you so much